# Jqgrid Keyboard Navigation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Below is a link to the jsfiddle. Here if we remove

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('sortableRows');
```

We are able to scroll the rows using keyboard navigation keys. But i want soratble rows as well. So when i added this i am able to sort the rows but key baord navigation does not work

Javascript code

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    sortable: true,
    height: 250,
       colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
       colModel:[
           {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
           {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
           {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
           {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
           {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},        
           {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},        
           {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}        
       ],
       multiselect: false,
       caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
});
var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
        ];
for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)

    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);


jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('bindKeys');
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('sortableRows');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTqD5/118/#&togetherjs=ptdwchkcKu

Regards,

Maclean Maurice Pinto

Answer (score 0):

There is the bind keys method which can be used in your case. Did you try that?

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods

According to the documentation:

> When called the method make it so that it is possible to select a row
>   with Up and Down keys - i.e we scroll the grid data with keys. It is
>   possible to invoke additional events when the row is selected and a
>   key like enter, space, left or right are pressed. To these events a
>   selected id of the row is passed as parameter.

Comment: @ I am not able to understand your English

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you solve this, but I had the same issue and the solution was to add this when you create the grid:

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
            $('#' + rowid).focus();
        }
```