# jqgrid sortableRows and bindKeys

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Reason why bindKeys doesn't work

```
$(selector).jqGrid("bindKeys", { "onEnter": function (rowid) { alert("You enter a row with id:" + rowid) } });
```

If I use sortableRows

```
$(selector).sortableRows();
```

this is jqGrid  4.6.0

Comment: In Guriddo jqGrid this problem is fixed in the [last build in GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ad71303535c0662ba31bb5f507a26d9d9b6ba8bc). You may want to look at [this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008602/jqgrid-keyboard-navigation-issue)

Comment: $($t).on('click', function(e) {
                $(e.target, $t.rows).closest("tr.jqgrow").focus();
            });


this resolve my problem

Comment: @HoangNguyen: If you have the solution of the problem then you should post *the answer* on your question and accept it later. It helps other to find your question and to see the solution way.

Answer (score 0):

As @Oleg said, I post the answer here.
@Tony Tomov also commented. This problem was fixed in 
[last build](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/ad71303535c0662ba31bb5f507a26d9d9b6ba8bc)
I pasted this code

```
            $($t).on('click', function(e) {
                $(e.target, $t.rows).closest("tr.jqgrow").focus();
            });
```

into line 3866 (jqGrid 4.6.0) then resolved my problem.